# Is it possible to stream data from google sheets into R?

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny, googlesheets4

Is it possible to get real-time data from google sheets into R?

Basically, I have a google sheet and I want to get data from it and display it in a shinyApp. But when the data in the google sheet changes/updates, it should also get updated in the shinyApp.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able

- to poll the data using [google-sheets-api](/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api) or
- push the changes from Google sheets using [installed `onEdit`/`onChange` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=en) in apps script(assuming you have a http end point to receive the push)

Comment: I am new to this and never used the google sheets API. Can you give some details and an example in R?

Comment: @MayurShende  No. I don't know R. I know the api and apps script.

Comment: @MayurShende Checkout https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4 and tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlesheets4 for samples